# How to Clicking "X" in Form, will not close it but hide it

Tags: c#, vb.net

how can i make my Form not to close but to Hide when user click on the "X" button on the form?

As i have a NotifyIcon that contain an Exit menu which actually does the Form Closing (i don't want the Form's "X" to close the form but to hide it).

thanks.

Comment: close deallocates the form, whereas hide makes it invisible and maintains state

Comment: Yes, prev comment removed. I was thinking about DialogResult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just implement the FormClosing event.  Cancel the close and hide the form unless it was triggered by the notify icon's context menu.  For example:

```
    Private CloseAllowed As Boolean

    Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)
        If Not CloseAllowed And e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
            Me.Hide()
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
        MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        CloseAllowed = True
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you just call Application.Exit() from the toolstrip item you do not need CloseAllowed.

Comment: nice, i'm changing it to Application.Exit(). thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle [Form.Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) event and set e.Cancel to true to stop the form from closing. To hide it call [Hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx) method.

Comment: ok, i have set e.Cancel=True but if i wanted to really closed the form then how? like using a menu Exit to close a form.

Comment: @jameslcs - Just call Application.Exit() from the toolstrip item click handler and examine e.CloseReason in FormClosing event handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.Hide()

End Sub
```